# how to display initial values taken from database for two way data binding in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I want to create an update page that the user can update `Recipe` values for. I know how to use two way data binding for creating new `Recipe`, but how do I load a page that has the values taken from the database loaded into the input fields initially?

So i have a model Recipe

```
export class Recipe {
  constructor(
      public name: String
  ) {}
}
```

in a RecipeComponent

```
import { Recipe } from './Recipe';

export class RecipeComponent {
  data = new Recipe('');
}
```

shown in an html form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
  required
  [(ngModel)]="data.name" />

<p>Hello {{ data.name }}!</p>
```

This works great if I want to create a new model from scratch. But I want the user to be able to see what the exiting values are, so somehow in the `data = new Recipe('')` line i want that to use my `RecipeService` to populate the inputs.

Comment: add the `RecipeService`'s code

Comment: first, you need to fetch the saved data from the server (use a service for this task) and then check if you are going to edit the Recipe (if yes fill the data from service)

Comment: U need a backend service that is a connection bridge with your angular and db. And write post or get service to take data from api. After that [(ngModel)] is already two way binding for u. If u dont put any submit button and want update to db with changind text  usen oninput and assign function to it send data to update in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo in this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tokkfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You need one service, and get data from service to component. and then bind it to [()] ng model.

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
 export class DataService {
  data = {
   name: 'wesbos'
  };
 constructor() { }
 getData(){
  return of(this.data);
 }
```

}

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = this.dataService.getData();
  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="name | async as dataName">
   default Name : <input [(ngModel)]="dataName.name">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, didnt realize that i could just load the model data right into input field

Comment: glad that works for you. You can UpVote answer too.